# asynchronous impromptu dialogs in jquery

Tags: jquery, impromptu

I'm using this code to save the content of a tab.

```
function first_save(close,num,focus){
    txt = '<form name="form">name of the file<br><input type="text" id="impromptu_fname" name="name"/></form>';
    $.promptExt(txt,{ 
        buttons:{Change:true, Cancel:false},
        loaded: function(){ $('#impromptu_fname').focus(); },
        submit: function(v,m,f){
            if(v){      
                $.get('/save/', { async:false,content:$('#tab'+num).data('editor').getValue(),name:f.name }, function(data){
                    if(close){
                        close_tab(num);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#th'+num+' a').text(f.name);
                        detect_mode(f.name,num);
                        $('#tab'+num).data('fname',f.name);
                        $('#tab'+num).data('last_save',$('#tab'+num).data('editor').getValue());
                        $('#th'+num+' a').css('color','black');
                        if(focus){
                            $('#tab'+num).data('editor').focus();
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#tab'+current).data('editor').focus();
                        }
                    }
                });                 
            }
            else{
                }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to implement a save all functionality where it would iterate through each tab and call that function. The problem is that the impromptu dialog is async and only the last one works. I want it to not continue to the next tab after the dialog has been answered and the file saved.